# Connecting to Subversion repository with SVNKit using HTTPS

Tags: java, https, svnkit

How to connect to Subversion repository with SVNKit using HTTPS?
I use the approach that worked earlier with http connection:

```
  DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
repositoryRoot = repository.getRepositoryRoot(false).toString();
```

I get the

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: Authentication required for '<https://daisy.interorigins.com:443> MY repository'
```

Comment: could you please provide your complete working code on svn connection so that i can get the big picture??

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURI**En**coded(url));
try SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url)
```